# How to get error log of a disutils setup in Python?

Tags: python, distutils

I am new to Python. I have created some C/C++ extensions for Python and able to build those with the help of Python disutils setup script. But, I have to integrate this setup script to an existing build system. So, I wrote another script to call this setup script using run_setup() method.

```
distributionObj = run_setup("setup.py",["build_ext"])
```

Now, I want if any error occurs during the building of extension (Compiler, Linker or anything), I must be able to get the information along with the error string from the caller script to notify the build process.

Please provide me some suggestion.

Answer (score 19):

Setting DISTUTILS_DEBUG=1 in the environment will cause debug logging.

Comment: `DISTUTILS_DEBUG=1 python setup.py develop` worked for me. `-v` didn't. (Python 2.7.6)

Comment: This also works even if you didn't call setup.py directly.

Answer (score 8):

**distutils1** (first version) uses too a internal version of logging (a bit hardcoded, it is not using the standard logging module). I think that it is possible to set the *verbosity level* coding something like:

```
import distutils.log
distutils.log.set_verbosity(-1) # Disable logging in disutils
distutils.log.set_verbosity(distutils.log.DEBUG) # Set DEBUG level
```

All distutils's logging levels available:

```
DEBUG = 1
INFO = 2
WARN = 3
ERROR = 4
FATAL = 5
```

You can see the source code of the class "Log" of distutils for reference. Usually for Python 2.7 in */usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/log.py*

Comment: I think you may have meant set_threshold(). Using set_verbosity() with DEBUG (1) appears to actually set the threshold to INFO (2) in https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e42b705188271da108de42b55d9344642170aa2b/Lib/distutils/log.py#L69, which is probably not the intended behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Passing the `-v` parameter to `python setup.py build` to increase verbosity usually works to get more detailed errors.

Answer (score 2):

The verbose option is not additive, it converts to a boolean. Thus no matter how many times you invoke the verbose option it will always be 1 and 1 always sets the level to INFO, which is the default anyway.